# Unity Android App Crashes On Test Device Immediately

Tags: android, crash, unity-game-engine, device

So I am porting my new app onto my crappy Hauwei that I just bought to test my app before release to the store.

Unity builds the app and the icon is on my test device, but as soon as I click the device, the app hardly even attempts to open before it crashes. Doesn't even get to the splash screen. This happened with Development Build checked AND unchecked.

This happens with any of my apps that I have made, big or small.

Any suggestions? I have no idea what's going on.

I am using a Mac with the latest version of OS X and Unity 4.0.3

:)

Comment: Stack trace from logcat please.

Comment: Do you mean show you the console errors?